# "Last Opened" Date

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How could I get a file's "last opened" date ? I know how to get modification date but I didn't find anything on last used or last opened.

I want to arrange my files as in finder.

Thank you for any help ! (sandboxable would be much appreciated)

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: maybe because thats the way you make apps?

Comment: Actually I don't. IDE != programming language != APIs etc. One does not need Xcode for writing apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the Spotlight metadata - the field you are interested in is `kMDItemLastUsedDate`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! However, is it possible to use this in a sandboxed app ?

Comment: I guess the best way to find out would be to try it.

Comment: did some research, and it turns out the spotlight index can be changed when it reindex the file

Answer (score -1):

If you mean "last accessed" date by "last opened" date, then there's a function in the C standard library for that:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat st;
stat("somefile.ext", &st);
time_t accessed = st.st_atime;
```

Comment: I think this gives a different date/time than that shown in the Finder, which uses Spotlight's `kMDItemLastUsedDate` field apparently.

Comment: @PaulR It may be the case, but why? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: I'm not sure that HFS+ actually stores atime, so it may just be that atime == mtime, hence the need to use Spotlight. Just guessing though...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would last accessed not also imply it could be opened by the system, instead of the user. Also, would this function work in a sandboxed app in your judgment ?

Comment: @CSS-code IDK why would it not work in any app. Also, this does mean that it can be accessed by anything - are you not looking for that? You didn't specify you wanted to restrict this check to user interaction...

Comment: sry, it was mend to be restricted by the user. as I said like in finder, which also only shows you the files the user accessed.

Comment: mh.. is there also a c way to get if the last opener was the user ?

Comment: yes thats sure, but a way to get the type of opener, for example if the last opener was a system app or not

Comment: is st_atime support better on APFS (Apple's new file-system)?  Is this API available (and not private) also on iOS? My goal is to find recently viewed Photos, when I have the photo-library access permission, and I can get to the file-URL of the locally stored image file.

Comment: Plus, is this Spotlight API also available for iOS?