# How to programmatically get the "last opened" date like displayed in Finder

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation, hfs+

I want to display the "Last opened" date in my App just like in the Finder preview or info panel. However I realized that this is NOT the same as the last access date that I would get with

```
NSDate* lastAccessDate = [fileUrl resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLContentAccessDateKey] error:NULL][NSURLContentAccessDateKey];
```

or with

```
struct stat buf;
stat(curName, &buf);
time_t lastAccessDate = buf.st_atimespec.tv_sec;
```

These return the the Unix last access time which is also displayed in Terminal for `ls -l`
However the Finder displays a different value which only changes when the file is opened by the user (e.g. via double clicking)

---

I read the posts ['Get the real “last opened” date?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914600/get-the-real-last-opened-date?lq=1) and  ['“Last Opened” Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844782/last-opened-date?rq=1) but these didn't solve it. They recommend something like

```
MDItemRef itemRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)fileUrl);
NSArray *attributeNames = (__bridge NSArray *)MDItemCopyAttributeNames(itemRef);
NSDictionary *attributes = (__bridge NSDictionary *) MDItemCopyAttributes(itemRef, (__bridge CFArrayRef) attributeNames);
CFDateRef lastUsedCfDate = MDItemCopyAttribute(itemRef, kMDItemLastUsedDate);
NSDate* lastUsedDate = (__bridge NSDate*) lastUsedCfDate;
CFRelease(itemRef);
```

But `attributeNames` does not have a value `kMDItemLastUsedDate`. In my case there are exactly 24 values in that array, but none for last use. So `lastUsedDate` is `nil`...

Also I wonder if there really is no high level API to access the last opened date.

Comment: Does `mdls` (on Terminal) show an entry for `kMDItemLastUsedDate`? Also, note that you are leaking `attributes` and `lastUsedCfDate`.

Comment: Ah, I played a bit with `mdls` and realized that the `kMDItemLastUsedDate` is not set for files that were copied but have not been opened, yet. However, the Finder does display a last opened time for these files, too. Can I manually set the `kMDItemLastUsedDate`? I ask, because I want to copy files and set all attributes to the values of the source file.

Comment: I’m not sure if you can set Spotlight attributes like you can with `xattr` (both the command-line utility and the API) unless you write a Spotlight importer. How are you copying the file? Have you tried `copyfile(3)`? `cp -p` copies some attributes but not `kMDItemLastUsedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=855913

To quote chown33:

> Extended attributes are completely different from metadata. Xattrs are attached to the file, stored as part of the file-system. Metadata is extracted from the file, stored in the metadata store (essentially, Spotlight's database). Some xattrs are extracted and stored in the metadata store, but they're still two separate things.
>
> The commands that operate on metadata fit the 'md*' globbing pattern: mdfind, mdls, mdutil, etc.
>
> ...
>
> You generally don't get to update any of the metadata values. This is by design, from what I can see by looking at the low-level API.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer the question. I know I can get the spotlight metadata using the md* commands. But I need to do this from Cocoa code and I would rather not create command line tasks and do console output parsing...

Comment: @codingFriend1, I was projecting my intentions on to you. I was trying to modify the metadata, but from what I found I think the answer to that is the metadata system was designed to disallow it. After re-reading your question, I see you're just trying to read the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same problem. I found that when Finder encounters a case where the `kMDItemLastUsedDate` key is unavailable, it will show you the value for the `kMDItemFSContentChangeDate` key instead.